# Problem with compiling code on Sharelatex

Tags: sharelatex

Here is the rather complicated input that will not compile for me in Sharelatex. ShareLatex simply will not compile it within my project. I am looking for help with restructuring the code and appreciate any advice you can offer.

```
 F_{\bar{X}_i}(x) = \left.


  \begin{cases}
        0,          & \text{if } x<0,\\
        1+e^{rT}\frac{C_i[K_{i,j+1}]-C_i[K_{i,j}{K_{i,j+1}-K_{i,j}},  & \text{if } K_{i,j} \leq x \leq K_{i,j+1}, j=-l_i,\dots,h_{i}+1\\
        1,              & \text{if } x \geq K_{i,h_{i}+1}.
  \end{cases}
  \right.
\end{displaystyle}    
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
F_{\bar{X}_i}(x) =
\[ \begin{cases} 
     0,          & \text{if } x<0,\\
        1+e^{rT}\frac{C_i[K_{i,j+1}]-C_i[K_{i,j}{K_{i,j+1}-K_{i,j}},  & \text{if } K_{i,j} \leq x \leq K_{i,j+1}, j=-l_i,\dots,h_{i}+1\\
        1,              & \text{if } x \geq K_{i,h_{i}+1}.
   \end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: i don't know about sharelatex, but the `\[ ... \]` within the `equation` environment are not valid, and would result in error messages in a non-sharelatex compilation.  also, blank lines within any math environment are illegal.  there are some other suspicious elements, but your example contains incomplete environments, so it's difficult to say more.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you Holene! I should have really researched the guidelines before I submitted my first post.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you had the same equation twice, so I only included one below. There are several things that were wrong, some mentioned by Barbara in the comment above:

- You were missing one closing brace in the `\frac`, that is you had `\frac{...{...}`, where it should have been `\frac{...}{...}`
- The `\left.` and `\right.` in the first should be removed. I guess it's a remnant from having used an array or something with `\left\{` instead of `cases`.
- There is no `\begin{equation}` in the first case, but you have both `\end{displaymath}` and `\end{equation}`. You only need one display math environment, so use either `displaymath` if you want an unnumbered equation (or the short form `\[ ... \]`), or `equation` if you want a numbered equation.
- There is no `\end{equation}` in the  second case.
- Empty lines are not allowed in displayed math environments.
- When you are inside a math environment like `\begin{equation} .. \end{equation}`, don't use other math environments such as `\[ .. \]`.
- Looks like there was also a `]` missing in the fraction in the second case, but that wouldn't produce any errors.
- The equation is a bit too wide for a standard `article`, but as I don't know what kind of page setup you have, I haven't tried doing anything about it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
F_{\bar{X}_i}(x) =
\begin{cases} 
  0,          & \text{if } x<0,\\
  1+e^{rT}
   \frac{
       C_i[K_{i,j+1}]-C_i[K_{i,j}]
         }{
        K_{i,j+1}-K_{i,j}
         },   & \text{if } K_{i,j} \leq x \leq K_{i,j+1}, j=-l_i,\dots,h_{i}+1\\
  1,          & \text{if } x \geq K_{i,h_{i}+1}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @torbjørn-t. Great answer to a poorly structured  question.